# How to turn a SQL Query Into Linq? "People who viewed this product also viewed this product."

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not really that good at linq so im having trouple trying to do groups and order by.

The goal of my query is, When someone is on a product page i want to show a list of products that people also viewed. I'm pretty sure this query is right but i have no idea how to to transfer to linq and get it to work in my C# project.

**The Sql Query im trying to change to linq is**

```
    select pv.ProductId,p.Name, count(*) as 'ProductCount'
    from Products p
    join ProductVieweds pv
    on p.ProductID = pv.ProductId
    where UserId in (
         select UserId
         from ProductVieweds pv
         where ProductID = 1 --The 1 in this example is the product the person is viewing.
         )
         and p.ProductID != 1 --change this
    group by pv.ProductId,p.Name
    order by 'ProductCount' desc
```

**What I've been able to do so far.**

```
    var sub = (
        from p in db.ProductsViewed
        where p.ProductId == product.ProductID
        select p.UserId).ToList();

    var products = (from p in db.Products
                        join pv in db.ProductsViewed on c.ProductID equals p.ProductId
                       where p.ProductID != currentProduct.ProductID
                       where sub.Contains(pv.UserId)
                       select p).GroupBy(c => c.ProductID).ToList();

        PeopleAlsoViewedModel model = new PeopleAlsoViewedModel
        {
            Products = products,
        };
```

**The Model**

```
      public class PeopleAlsoViewedModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

So i want to be able to group by Products and order by the count but i dont know how to do this and still get a IEnumerable< Product >. Please any help will be awesome, and if your gonna down vote at least tell me why.

Comment: your question little bit confusing ? can explained more details

Comment: @NazmulHasan I'm not that sure how to but i'll try. When i use .GroupBy(c => c.ProductID) it returns an IGrouping<int, Product> but what i want is what ToList() returns normally which is a List< Product >. To return a List< Product > i think i cant use .GroupBy(). After doing some research after posting this questions i found i can do

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured how to solve my problem and thought i should post it incase anyone reads this later.

The Query will look like this in C#

```
    var products = (from c in db.Products
                        join p in db.ProductsViewed on c.ProductID equals p.ProductId
                       where c.ProductID != CurrentProduct.ProductID
                       where sub.Contains(p.UserId)
                       group c by c.ProductID into productGrouped
                       orderby productGrouped.Key
                       select productGrouped).SelectMany(group => group.Distinct()).ToList();
```

The SelectMany() turns the List< IGrouping< key, element>> into List< Element> I put distinct because multiple people can view the same product otherwise it returns duplicates.